# Flaw in audit system: close votes

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-audits

If I review close votes and click on one of the "by type" choices, for instance, "duplicates", I only get to see questions that are being voted to close as duplicates, naturally.

Except if one of the entries I get is a review audit; then the close vote can be anything else, such as "too broad".

So when the close reason is anything but "duplicate", I will know instantly that this is a review audit.

Is this by design? I believe it's a bug. Not that I mind, really; review audits like this  are easy to detect and easily overcome, so it's not a problem for me. Still, I don't think it was designed to be this way.

Comment: Not a problem; the other post is about using tag filters, this is about close vote type filters. Not directly obvious I'd say, but the answer is the same.