# Should I report strange/dubious review tests (here)?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, disputed-review-audits

I just passed a strange 'first answer' review test.

It said 'the system marked this post as possible spam' but it had nothing to do with spam. It only contained text and valid code. It had to be rejected for another reason (the suggested answer was not an answer), so in itself it was not an invalid test, but the spam messages were misleading. You could argue that the test *itself* was not even disputable.

Should I report such a question here so that it can be removed from the review pool?

If yes, what do I report to identify the review item - the URL?

Sorry, can't find that question back. It's not in my activity/reviews list - not so strange for a review test ;-)

Comment: Are you sure that it was an audit? Did you get the "congratulations" message after you clicked the button? I got the "possible spam" message for a post in a review queue the other day, and it was not an audit, as far as I recall. It looked like an automated script might have thrown the post into the review queue. It was not spam at all.

Comment: Yes and yes (as I wrote, the post had to be rejected for another reason).

Answer (score 4):

Those review audits are meant to see if you're paying attention.
So if they have the wrong flag reason, you should react to that by indicating it's not the right flag, i.e. click "No action needed".

I have also fallen into this trap, see my questions [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267212/1016716) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/218042/184981).